# How to do conditional computation of rowMeans in R?

Tags: r

I would like to compute rowMeans across several variables, but ***only*** if at least 80% of the data is present. In the first example, the mean should be computed for the first row only. In the second, no means should be computed. How do I make this happen?

```
x <- c(1, 2)
y <- c(1, 2)
z <- c(1, NA)
z1 <- c(1, NA)
z2 <- c(1, NA)
df <- data.frame(x, y, z, z1, z2)
df$means <- rowMeans(df)
df

  x y  z z1 z2 means
1 1 1  1  1  1     1
2 2 2 NA NA NA    NA

x <- c(1, 2)
y <- c(1, 2)
z <- c(1, 2)
z1 <- c(1, 2)
z2 <- c(1, NA)
df <- data.frame(x, y, z, z1, z2)
df$means <- rowMeans(df)
df

   x  y   z z1 z2    means
1  1  1   1  1  1      1
2  2  2   2  2  NA     2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like this?

```
transform(df, means = apply(df, 1, function(x)
    ifelse(sum(is.na(x)) / length(x) < 0.2, mean(x, na.rm = T), NA)))
#  x y  z z1 z2 means
#1 1 1  1  1  1     1
#2 2 2 NA NA NA    NA
```

Explanation: We calculate the fraction of `NA`s per row, and only return the row mean if the fraction is <0.2 (i.e. the row contains at least 80% non-`NA` values).

Answer (score 0):

Another fully vectorized approach where we calculate the means for all rows first.

```
df1$means <- rowMeans(df1, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Now we replace those value by `NA` where there are less then 80% non-`NA`s per row.

```
old_cols <- setdiff(names(df1), "means")
NA_rows <- 1 - rowMeans(is.na(df1[, old_cols])) < 0.8
df1[NA_rows, "means"] <- NA
df1
#  x y  z z1 z2 means
#1 1 1  1  1  1     1
#2 2 2 NA NA NA    NA
```

**data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(x = c(1, 2), y = c(1, 2), z = c(1, NA), z1 = c(1, 
NA), z2 = c(1, NA)), .Names = c("x", "y", "z", "z1", "z2"), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = "data.frame")
```